# Convert string to 2d array (java)

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to convert string like this:

```
{"Shops":[
{"city":"Riga","shops":[{"a":"some info here","b":"...","c":"..."},{"a":"some info here","b":"...","c":"..."}]},{"city":"Liepaja","shops":[{"a":"info here","b":"info....","c":"..."}]
]}
```

to 2d array, like

```
shops[0][0]=>{"a":"some info here","b":"...","c":"..."}
shops[1][0]=>{"a":"info here","b":"info....","c":"..."}
```

Is it possible? Is there some easy way to do that?

I've searched, tried, but I still don't know how to do that.
I'm new in java.

Comment: It's very hard to see what is exactly you want to do. Please format your code to make it clear and clarify how these two array entries relate to the original string.

Comment: Are you sure this is java?  It looks like javascript...

Comment: Take a look at the [JSON processing API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html).

Comment: It would probably be better for you to make a City object that has within it a list of shops.  It would make more sense and be easier to handle than a 2d array, and you won't lose the city names, as you currently are with the 2d array.

Comment: Thanks! I was stuck here almost 4 days.. And it turns out to be so easy.. :D

Answer (score 1):

That is a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) string. There are a number of libraries that will do this for you.

- [JSON in Java](http://json.org/java/)
- [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like JSON data, and you should treat it as such.

Try a JSON parsing library for Java. I like [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for its simplicity. Take a look at the Gson.fromJson() set of methods.

Answer (score 0):

The type of data you have posted is JSON encoded. you could use a [json encoder and decoder](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) to do this job easily.